# JDBC driver authenticating to Oracle RDBMS using OpenID authentication?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am wondering about the following:

A JDBC driver authenticating a user to a remote Oracle RDBMS using OpenID authentication.
In this instance the Oracle RDBMS will NOT see the user's password.

1. Is it possible to setup Oracle RDBMS to be an OpenID Relying Party? If so, what versions can be setup this way?
2. Is there a JDBC driver that can act as a User Agent that can handle the HTTP(S) redirections and such inherent in OpenID authentication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ha a look at Oracle Identity Federation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I did look at OIF briefly and while it does support OpenID as a Relying Party or an Identity Provider, references to JDBC in the OIF documentation all seemed to refer to JDBC between the OIF server and a backend datasource for authentication data. But what I am looking for is a JDBC driver that authenticates itself to an Oracle RDBMS using OpenID instead of username/password, Kerberos, or SSL client certificate.

Comment: Well the jdbc driver cannot do that. What is required is support from the oracle rdbms to support openid authentication. As far as I know this is not provided.